# Why is there no javafx.util.pair? Is this a bug in eclipse?

Tags: java, java-11

I use jdk11 in eclipse and there is no library for pair?
or I need to add external jars?

Comment: You need `JavaFx`...

Comment: Or rethink whether it is worth adding a large, bloated UI library when all you need is a trivial pair type for holding two references. You could use `Map.entry(a, b)` or just `class Pair<A,B> { A a; B b; }`.

Comment: JavaFX was deleted in java11, you can add library at your own, write this class because it is simple or i recommend you using Tuple from vavr.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed that with external jars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Add *OpenJFX* libraries to your project

[*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io/), the open-source implementation of [JavaFX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) hosted on the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project, is not bundled with many of the builds of OpenJDK supplied by some vendors.

You must choose one of these three solutions:

- Download the OpenJFX libraries and manually add to your project
- Use a dependency & build tool such as *Maven* or *Gradle* to download and install the OpenJFX libraries.
- Obtain your build of OpenJDK from a vendor that chooses to bundle the OpenJFX library. I know of two:  [*LibericaFX*](https://bell-sw.com/) from BellSoft, and [*ZuluFX*](https://www.azul.com/blog/zulu-gets-graphical-with-openjfx/) from Azul Systems.

## Other “Pair” solutions

If you are not building JavaFX gui apps, and just want a class to hold a [pair of values like a key-value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair), then adding JavaFX implementation to get [`javafx.util.Pair`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/util/Pair.html) is overkill. Seek an alternative.

One alternative is to write your own `Pair` class. Simple enough.

As of Java 16+, define a custom class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```
record Point ( int x , int y ) {}
```

Another example:

```
record DayAssignment ( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek , Employee employee ) {}
```

Another alternative is to use the [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface built into Java. Two implementations are built in, one mutable and one immutable.

As the name suggests, the original purpose of this class is to hold the key and value pair as an entry in a `Map` implementation object. But some folks use this interface and classes separately, without a map.

- [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,​V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)
- [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<K,​V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)

Example. Let’s track who is working on a particular [day-of-week](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).

```
AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry< DayOfWeek , String > dayWorker = 
        new SimpleImmutableEntry<>( 
            DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY , 
            "Alice" 
        )
;

DayOfWeek dow = dayWorker.getKey() ;    // DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY
String worker = dayWorker.getValue() ;  // "Alice"
```

Comment: But mind that the OP didn’t wonder about the absence of JavaFX in general. The question was only about the pair type, which suggests that the solution should be something other than installing the entire JavaFX for the sake of getting one, rather trivial class…

Comment: @Holger I added a second section to my Answer to address your point. Thank you.